# Get privileges with role hierarchy - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

For example, I have a role called **ROLE_USER** that has some privileges like **READ_POST**, **READ_MESSAGE** and **ROLE_ADMIN** that has **EDIT_POST**, **EDIT_MESSAGE**, all of which are stored in database table roles and privileges. Then having some APIs that can add, edit, delete roles and privileges.

I know that Spring Security supports role hierarchy and my role hierarchy is **ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER**, but how can I make the spring get the user privileges from my database if the current authentication has **ROLE_ADMIN**?

Answer (score 0):

Just for example,
plz check out the following source:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    JDBCUserService userService;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf((csrf)
                        -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/demo/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((ah)
                        -> ah
                        //Here is the ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER setting.
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE", "USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/employee").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .userDetailsService(userService);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class JDBCUserService implements UserDetailsService  {
    @Autowired
    DataSource ds;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userm = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(ds);
        //you can use userm.setXXXSql method here to make your own sql dsl.
        UserDetails u = userm.loadUserByUsername(username);
        return u;
    }
}
```